# Hangfire background Job with schedule

Tags: hangfire

Is there a way to have recurring schedule for background job in hangfire ?
I have tried the following but it only fires it once.

```
 using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer(options))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
               // Console.ReadKey();
            }
            return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule a job with hangfire like this:

```
 Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Schedule<VerificationEmail>((j) => j.FollowUpVerficationEmail(Email), TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

Here `VerificationEmail` is the class which contains `FollowUpVerficationEmail` method to send follow up emails after every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

If you want recurring schedule work or want to execute method for any particular date or day of months. For Cron expressions, you need to follow
[this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14003_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm)

for example:

```
DateTime date =
                DateTime.Parse(ScheduleTime, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                    .ToUniversalTime();
            var dateString = ScheduleTime.Minute + " " + ScheduleTime.Hour + " " + ScheduleTime.ScheduleDate + " * *";

            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IClassController>(
                "RecurringName", s => s.Execute(MViewModel),
                dateString);


    public async Task<bool> Execute(MViewModel mViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (mViewModel.ExpiryDate != null && mViewModel.ExpiryDate.Value < DateTime.Now)
            {
                RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("RecurringName");
            }
            else
            {
                var url = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiPath"];
                string apiUrl = url + "api/VApi/CallAPi";

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        "bW9iaWxlYXBw");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mViewModel);

                    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, serializedJson);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Log(LogType.Error, ExceptionType.Application, ToString(), exception);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use RecurringJob to create it. [Hangfire Recurring Tasks](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html)

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("some-id", () => Console.WriteLine(), Cron.Hourly);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(/*(optional) job Id*/,() => /*do your stuff here */, /*Cron Expression*/);
```

**1)** You can choose your cron expression by **HangFire's Cron** class as shown below

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("job1", () => Console.WriteLine("hey"), Cron.Hourly);
```

**2)** Or you can specify your cron expression via [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html),

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("job2", () => Console.WriteLine("hey"), "0/10 0 0 ? * * *");
```

And you can check [here](https://www.hangfire.io/) for more details.